# Is Whitespace preferable to null for database storage

Tags: database

I'm using rails 3 and either Mysql or SQlite3 as my backend database.  I'm importing a lot of comma separated values form a third party.  When ever a particular attribute is null the third party uses  " " (1 space or whitespace for the value).

My question is from a database efficiency perspective should I simply stick with the third party convention of using whitespace or would I be better converting the whitespace to a null character.

Comment: I guess you're using Rails, but your question doesn't really have anything to do with Rails, does it?

Comment: Only to the extent that activerecord has some sort of preference that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert them to NULL. It makes Your furute work easier if the data is NULL when it should be NULL and not some random whitespace. 
The truth is, You can convert it to anything, but keeping the data as consistent as possible is one of the most important things if You want a bugless system.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NULL` because it means there is no value for that field. But an empty space, is actually a value (which is a space), so you'd better convert them to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

While NULL is preferred than white space, more than a few NULL data represent a database design smell.

I suggest you to:

1. Import the database as it is, i.e., white space
2. Use raw SQL commands to convert white space into NULL.
3. If lot of NULLs, redesign your models and migrate.